# HTML5 Geolocation + Ajax Request: Ajax firing before Lat/Long

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, geolocation

I have a form I'm trying to populate with the closest address to a user (using Google's Reverse Geocode API).  That means I need to send latitude and longitude to an Ajax script, but **my problem is that the lat/long aren't resolving before the Ajax call is being made**.  The code I'm using for lat/long calculation is below.  Any idea how to make sure the Ajax call happens AFTER the geolocation is received (or cancelling out if it's not) without using a `sleep` call or some other hack solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var lat, long;

function savePosition(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    long = position.coords.longitude;
    //alert("Lat = "+lat+"\nLong = "+long);
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    function initialize() {
        var location = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(savePosition);
        //lat = location.coords.latitude;
        //long = location.coords.longitude;
        //alert(lat+","+long);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "./address.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { lat: lat, long: long }
        }).done(function(result) {
            alert(result);
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

**EDIT** Tried to follow the comment's advice and made it the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    var lat, long;
    function savePosition(position) {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        long = position.coords.longitude;
        alert("Lat = "+lat+"\nLong = "+long);
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "./address.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: { lat: lat, long: long }
        }).done(function(result) {
            alert(result);
        });
    }

    function initialize() {
        var location = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(savePosition);
        //lat = location.coords.latitude;
        //long = location.coords.longitude;
        alert(lat+","+long);
    }

    initialize();
});
</script>
```

But now the savePosition function isn't getting called at all when I set a breakpoint in it on Chrome.  Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Geolocation is asynchronous as well. Simply make your AJAX call inside the handler function, `savePosition`.

Comment: Tried it, now the savePosition function isn't firing at all.  See my edit for what I changed it to.